# Two-dimensional Array as an object

Tags: python, arrays

I'm asking you guys if there's any way to create a two-dimensional Array as a class. I'm trying to complete a task and I couldn't find any research about this on google.

If someone knows any solution with extra interpretation and/or explanation, please hit me up.

(something like this:)

```
class Array (object):
    def __init__ (self, row = 0, col = 0, el = 0):
       self.row = row
       self.col = col
       self.el = el
```

Comment: The practical answer is to use [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/). This question as it stands is very broad though.

Comment: I guess there's no other way but using NumPy?

Comment: There are plenty of other ways, you could certainly write yourself a 2D array class if you wanted. It depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm a beginner and trying to make an object to behave like a 2D inherited array would sound like a great heavy and impossible job. But, thank you for assuring me that this /is/ actually possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Array(object):
    def __init__(self,row = [], col = [], el = []):
        self.row = row
        self.col = col
        self.el = el

# here testing ->

test = Array([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9])
print(test.col)
>>> [4,5,6]

# adding to it

test.col.append[4]

#testing
print(test.col)
[4,5,6,4]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [numpy](http://cs231n.github.io/python-numpy-tutorial/) python package that has [N-dimensional array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.ndarray.html) (2D, 3D, 4D, ... nD) ready to use, however, If you want to understand how vector2D created, here is a simple example:

```
class Vector2(object):
    def __init__(self, x=float(0.0), y=float(0.0)):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y
    def get_x(self):
        return self._x
    def set_x(self, value=float):
        self._x = float(value)
    x = property(get_x, set_x)
    X = property(get_x, set_x)
    def get_y(self):
        return self._y
    def set_y(self, value=float):
        self._y = float(value)
    y = property(get_y, set_y)
    Y = property(get_y, set_y)
    def __add__(self, v):
        return Vector2(self._x + v.x, self._y + v.y)
    def __radd__(self, v):
        return Vector2(v.x + self._x, v.y + self._y)
    def __sub__(self, v):
        return Vector2(self._x - v.x, self._y - v.y)
    def __rsub__(self, v):
        return Vector2(v.x - self._x, v.y - self._y)
    def __eq__(self, v):
        return self._x == v.x and self._y == v.y and self._z == v.z
    def __str__(self):
        return '(%.4f,%.4f)' % (self._x, self._y)

>>> point1 = Vector2(10, 20.1)
>>> point1.x = 50
>>> point2 = Vector2(20, 10)
>>> point1 += point2
>>> print point1 
(70.0000,30.1000)
>>> point1 == point2
False
```

try to use **property** and class's **built-in Methods** (Magic Methods) to your advantage.
you can read about class built-in methods in [here](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_magic_methods.php)

Cheers